# How to get a value on angular typescript in json

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

Here is my json respond using **laravel spatie**  I created a respond that show if the user is have an **Roles**

```
{
"message": "Successfuly fetch all User",
"error": false,
"error_code": 200,
"line": "line 117 UserController.php",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "dasdsa",
        "email": "dasdsad@gmail.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T13:37:41.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T13:37:41.000000Z",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "publisher",
                "guard_name": "web",
                "created_at": "2020-04-23T11:11:33.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-04-23T11:11:33.000000Z",
                "pivot": {
                    "model_id": 1,
                    "role_id": 2,
                    "model_type": "App\\User"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "mdsadsadn",
        "email": "dasdsad@gmail.coms",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-04-23T10:37:10.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-23T12:04:46.000000Z",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "publisher",
                "guard_name": "web",
                "created_at": "2020-04-23T11:11:33.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-04-23T11:11:33.000000Z",
                "pivot": {
                    "model_id": 2,
                    "role_id": 2,
                    "model_type": "App\\User"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

and this is my code on **angular 9.1.3** to get the value name in roles array

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
roles:any;
result:any;
constructor(private _userService:UsersService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {


 this.getallUser();
 }

getallUser(){
this._userService.getallUsers().subscribe((event : HttpEvent<any>) => { 

        if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {

            if (event.status == 200) {

                let body  = event.body;
                let error = body.error;
                let msg   = body.message;
                //alert(body);
                // console.log(body.data);

                if (!error) {
                    this.dataTbl.tblVal = body.data
                    this.roles = body.data.roles;

                    console.log(this.roles)
                     // this.result = this.roles.map(a => a.roles);
                     // console.log(this.result);


                    // console.log(this.dataTbl.tblVal)
                }
            }


        }

        this.dataTbl.tblLoad = false;



    }, (err : HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err);
    });     
 }
}
```

Here is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class UsersService {

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { 

} 

getallUsers() {

    return this._httpClient.get("http://localhost:8000/api/getallUser", { 
    observe: 'response', reportProgress: true });
    }
  }
```

My problem is I want to get the value of name in roles **example:publisher** but i cannot access on that object how to get that value the error is undefined I dont know what's wrong with my code thank you for the help

Comment: Add your `getallUsers()` method to the question text.

Comment: Hi sir I edit my code in getallUser()

Comment: I was referring to `this._userService.getallUsers()`. How does it work?

Comment: sorry for the late reply i already indicate my this._userService.getallUsers()

Comment: Roles is an array, so you should map it again, for example: console.log(body.data.map(a => console.log(a.roles.map(b => console.log(b.name)))))